# Android surfaceview camera stretched

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, surfaceview

I have an activity with action bar, SurfaceView (fullScreen, Behind the action bar) and a capture button at the bottom of the screen but on the surfaceView.
in the SurfaceViewChange I'm scanning all the supported Picture Sizes and chosing the Highest, but when I'm putting the same values in the Preview the outcome is stretched and if I take a picture it look ok, If I'm using the device screen height and width for the preview than its not stretched but at the result picture there are thing that were off frame.
All I want is an activity that takes picture with the highest resolution supported and preview it fine and play around with the captured picture.

The activity is in portrait!

any ideas?

Comment: Scratched or stretched?

Comment: stretched sorry my mistake

Answer (score 2):

The aspect ratio of the SurfaceView needs to match the aspect ratio of the camera preview.  You can do this with a custom FrameLayout class.

For an example, see [AspectFrameLayout](https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/src/com/android/grafika/AspectFrameLayout.java) in Grafika.  You can see it used in the "Show + capture camera" and "Continuous capture" activities.  Note how it's used in the [layouts](https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/res/layout/activity_continuous_capture.xml).  Once you have it set up, you make one call with the camera preview parameters to set the desired aspect ratio, and the layout adjusts to match.